# Solrcloud instance are not work properly

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I got a problem in Solrcloud. It working perfectly in recent days but last two days, there is not enough for data, so I increase storage in my digitalOcean and restart sever, And now I got following error.

```
625  INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Loading solr.xml from SolrHome (not found in ZooKeeper) 
628  INFO  (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrXmlConfig Loading container configuration from /var/solr/data/solr.xml
629  ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.s.SolrDispatchFilter Could not start Solr. Check solr/home property and the logs
669  ERROR (main) [   ] o.a.s.c.SolrCore null:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load SOLR configuration
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromFile(SolrXmlConfig.java:116)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromSolrHome(SolrXmlConfig.java:140)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.loadNodeConfig(SolrDispatchFilter.java:188)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.createCoreContainer(SolrDispatchFilter.java:156)
at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.init(SolrDispatchFilter.java:134)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.FilterHolder.initialize(FilterHolder.java:137)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.initialize(ServletHandler.java:856)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.startContext(ServletContextHandler.java:348)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startWebapp(WebAppContext.java:1379)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1341)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:772)
at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler.doStart(ServletContextHandler.java:261)
at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:517)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardStarter.processBinding(StandardStarter.java:41)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:188)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:499)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:147)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.WebAppProvider.fileAdded(WebAppProvider.java:458)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:529)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:392)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.doStart(Scanner.java:313)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.doStart(ScanningAppProvider.java:150)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.startAppProvider(DeploymentManager.java:561)
at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.doStart(DeploymentManager.java:236)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:132)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.start(Server.java:405)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.doStart(ContainerLifeCycle.java:114)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.AbstractHandler.doStart(AbstractHandler.java:61)
at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.doStart(Server.java:372)
at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration$1.run(XmlConfiguration.java:1510)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.eclipse.jetty.xml.XmlConfiguration.main(XmlConfiguration.java:1435)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.invokeMain(Main.java:214)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.start(Main.java:457)
at org.eclipse.jetty.start.Main.main(Main.java:75)


Caused by: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException: /var/solr/data/solr.xml
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:84)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newByteChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:214)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:361)
at java.nio.file.Files.newByteChannel(Files.java:407)
at java.nio.file.spi.FileSystemProvider.newInputStream(FileSystemProvider.java:384)
at java.nio.file.Files.newInputStream(Files.java:152)
at org.apache.solr.core.SolrXmlConfig.fromFile(SolrXmlConfig.java:111)
... 46 more
```

So, it error is zookeeper doesn't found solr.xml file but it exist under solr.home location. I search from google but didn't found proper answer for this solution.

Comment: I am currently running solr version 6.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change the permission or ownership of the folder `/var/solr`**

If you are running solr from solr user then change the ownership to solr user by the below command for linux

```
sudo chown -R solr:solr /var/solr
```

This will change the ownership of that folder recursively to user solr